# Pandas Efficiency with small data

Tags: python, performance, pandas, memory

I am just curious!
Is there any lower limit, on which we shouldn't use pandas?

Using pandas for large data is good, considering the efficiency and readability.

But is there any lower limit on which we must use traditional looping(Python 3) over pandas?

When should I consider using pandas or numpy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know pandas is using numpy (vector operations) under the hood quite extensively. Numpy is faster than python because it low level and has more memory friendly behaviour than python (in many cases). But it depends what you are doing of course. For numpy based operations pandas should have same performance than numpy of course.

- For general vector like (eg. column wise apply) operations it will always be faster to use numpy / pandas.
- "for" loops in python eg. over pandas dataframe rows are slow.
- If you need to apply non vectorized key based lookups in pandas. Better go with something like dictionaries

Use pandas when you need time series or data frame like structures. Use numpy if you can organise your data in matrices / vectors (arithmetics).

**Edit:**
For very small python object, native python might be faster because low level libraries introduce small overhead!

Numpy example:

```
In [21]: a = np.random.rand(10)

In [22]: a
Out[22]: 
array([ 0.60555782,  0.14585568,  0.94783553,  0.59123449,  0.07151141,
        0.6480999 ,  0.28743679,  0.19951774,  0.08312469,  0.16396394])

In [23]: %timeit a.mean()
5.16 µs ± 24.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

For loop example:

```
In [24]: b = a.tolist()

In [25]: b
Out[25]: 
[0.6055578242263301,
 0.14585568245745317,
 0.9478355284829876,
 0.5912344944487721,
 0.07151141037216913,
 0.6480999041895205,
 0.2874367896457555,
 0.19951773879879775,
 0.0831246913880146,
 0.16396394311100215]

In [26]: def mean(x):
    ...:     s = 0
    ...:     for i in x:
    ...:         s += i
    ...:     return s / len(x)
    ...: 

In [27]: mean(b)
Out[27]: 0.37441380071208025

In [28]: a.mean()
Out[28]: 0.37441380071208025

In [29]: %timeit mean(b)
608 ns ± 2.24 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Ooops, python for loop is faster here. I it seems that numpy creates a small overhead (maybe from interfacing to c) at each timit iteration. 
So lets try with longer arrays.

```
In [34]: a = np.random.rand(int(1e6))

In [35]: %timeit a.mean()
599 µs ± 18.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [36]: b = a.tolist()

In [37]: %timeit mean(b)
31.8 ms ± 102 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Ok, so my conclusion is that there is some minimum object size from which on the usage of low level libs like numpy and pandas pays back. If someone likes please feel free to repeat the experiment with pandas

Comment: So its better to use pandas over traditional for loop!

Even if we have a requirement like, 10 rows and want to find the mean(eg).

Comment: @VaisakhRajagopal, id did a small experiment. For small objects pure python may be faster (at least for small lists). See my edit

Comment: @VaisakhRajagopal, thanks for the hint. i fixed it. i seemed to copy the numpy code twice. now it should be correct?